# Error calling the me/joinedGroups endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an App that is calling MS Graph API, and was working totally fine until 4-5 days ago. Suddenly, I´m getting an issue calling the `me/joinedGroups` endpoint.

The error is also happening using the Graph Explorer. It works fine with the dummy tenant, and also with other tenants we have, so it seems like something with just one specific tenant.

This is the error message I´m getting:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Unified groups aren´t supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ae03e478-d6c5-497a-a6e6-2401e6175988",
            "date": "2017-08-16T15:30:02"
        }
    }
}
```

I don´t think is a permissions issue, as it is working fine on other tenants.  I can also call the `/groups` endpoint (and some others) successfully. So, if I can get all the groups, I should be able to get my joined groups.

*I got attention from the great Yina Arenas (thanks again), from MS, and [she asked me to post the issue here](https://twitter.com/yina_arenas/status/898214753956274180)*

Comment: Seems MS is outsourcing their helpdesk to SO, too. Would be better she had answered you.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following are working for me in graph explorer, and they are fully supported.

You can use both of these alternatives *(not the same thing):

1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedgroups
2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberof

Option 1 is more directed to "UnifiedGroups", while Option 2 is directory objects, and would give you more back than you likely expect.

That error may be because groups are not enabled in a tenant. I haven't played around with graph explorer extensively, I wonder how or if you had signed into into graph explorer. Depending on the circumstances, that this could have caused such an issue for example if you were signed into a tenant with the feature blocked. It does seem to work fine now, regardless. If this comes up try it in an inprivate browser to make doubely sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was long time ago, and at some point it worked again. I think it was also because some users didn´t have an inbox assigned.

Comment: That would do it too. This information comes from a user's mailbox since it is their joined groups. Out of curiosity what was the scenario where you had been trying to do this with a user that doesn't have a mailbox. If it was "administration" i would have expected you to be rooted to graph/Groups rather than me or user.